# Convergence rate of Ito process path

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, brownian-motion, pointwise-convergence

Let $|t-t_0|=O(\alpha_n)$ and $dX_t = \mu_t dt + \sigma_t dB_t$ with $X_0=0$.
Then what is the convergence rate of the Ito process for a given realized path $\omega$, i.e.,
$$
|X_t(\omega) - X_{t_0}(\omega)| = O(?).
$$

**What I have tried.**

Using the mean value theorem, we have $|X_t(\omega)-X_{t_0}(\omega)|=\left|X'_{t^*}(\omega)(t-t_0) \right|$.
So If $X'_{t_0}(\omega)$ is well-defined,  due to $|t^*-t_0|\le|t-t_0|=O(\alpha_n)$, we have $O(\alpha_n)$ unless $X'_{t_0}(\omega)=0$.
However, it is well known that the Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable, so $X'_{t_0}(\omega)$ is not defined for all $t_0$.
The only thing that I can know is that since $X_t(\omega)$ is continuous, $X_t(\omega)\rightarrow X_{t_0}(\omega)$ anyway.
So is it possible to obtain the convergence rate of the above Ito process?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the bounded condition for absolute moments of $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$, it's
$$
 |X_t(\omega) - X_{t_0}(\omega)| = O_p(\sqrt{\alpha_n \log(1/\alpha_n)}).
$$
It's kind of [Lévy's modulus of continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_modulus_of_continuity_theorem).

For the detail, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604050/modulus-of-continuity-of-ito-process).